# Where can I get previous ftp connections information after resetting workspace in eclipse with aptana plugin?

Tags: eclipse, aptana

I work on eclipse with Aptana plugin.
For some reason I had to reset my workspace and new workspace does not contain any of my ftp connections information (which were on previous workspace). How can I get those connections back.
Note: I have previous workspace saved with different name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a file named `connections.2` under the directory 
`C:\Users[Username]\eclipse_workspace.metadata.plugins\com.aptana.ide.core.io`

which contained my connections information.